Proving that a graph's chromatic number is always greater than or equal to its chromatic index.
I want to prove that a graph's chromatic number is always greater than or equal to its chromatic index, but i dont have much idea on where to start.

Take the graph on points $v,w_1,w_2,w_3$ connecting ${v,w_i}$ for each $i$ by an edge. The chromatic number of this graph is 2 but it's chromatic index is 3.
